# System.Diagnostics.Process: when I run a C++ program that creates an output file and writes something, the output file is not created

Tags: c#, file

When I run a C++ program that creates an output file and writes something, the output file is not created, although the program works fine when I simply double click it from Windows Explorer.

This is the C# code I use to run the program:

```
            try
            {
                Process p = StartProcess(ExecutableFileName);
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
                Log("Program finished in " + ((p.ExitTime - p.StartTime).Milliseconds / 1000m) + " seconds with code " + p.ExitCode + "\n");
            }
            catch
            {
                Log("The program couldn't be started.");
            }
```

**UPDATE**

I just found out why it's happening.

Apparently, when I launch it with C#, the C++ program doesn't see the input file in the relative directory, but when I explicitly specify it

```
ifstream in("C:\\Alex\\primes.in");
```

it gets it and everything works! Now I need to make it work with relative file paths...

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: Did you try setting the `UseShellExecute` property to `true`?

Comment: Is the file created using an absolute path or a relative?

Comment: Is the file created in the current directory?

Comment: Find it via this: `cmd.exe` -> `cd \ ` -> `dir /a /s whateverYourFilenameIs.log`

Comment: No, I don't get any exceptions. The problem is that the C++ program that is run, can't access the files in the same directory correctly. It has to read data from an *.in file, but it can't. However when I double click this C++ program, it works correctly.

Comment: @Patrick, relaive. @Roman Kuzmin, yes

Comment: Silly, but double check what exactly the current directory is when you call the application (dump/trace System.Environment.CurrentDirectory). Perhaps, it is not what you think, and the output file is actually there.

Comment: I just found out why it's happening. Apparently, when I launch it with C#, the C++ program doesn't see the input file in the relative directory, but when I explicitly specify it (ifstream in("C:\\Alex\\primes.in");), it gets it and everything works! Now I need to make it work with relative file paths...

Comment: @Roman Kuzmin, yes! That's where the output file goes - to C# program's debug folder, not the folder where the C++ file is. Now how can I override it?

Comment: For debugging: you can specify the process startup directory, see the project settings (set it to the directory where your C++ app is). For production... there are a number of ways, it depends on your design. There is not enough information to give the right answer, I afraid.

Comment: @Roman Kuzmin,  I solved the problem by specifying the WorkingDirectory property. Please make a post so I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the summary of our discussion of the problem. It turned out that the output file was in the C# program's debug folder, not in the directory where the C++ application was and the output was expected. The problem is solved by specifying the Working directory property of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You must call Close() on process like so:

```
            try
            {
                Process p = StartProcess(ExecutableFileName);
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();

                //THIS HERE
                p.Close();                    

                Log("Program finished in " + ((p.ExitTime - p.StartTime).Milliseconds /1000m) + " seconds with code " + p.ExitCode + "\n");


            }
            catch
            {
                Log("The program couldn't be started.");
            }
```

Comment: Still, the process can't read/write information from/to files in the same directory correctly...

Comment: How are you starting it? You must provide absolute paths to the files you want to read/write... well I tried to help. =)

Comment: What is the value of `ExecutableFileName`?

Comment: Yes, the path to the process is absolute

Comment: No the path to the process, but the paths to the files. If you must use relative file paths, you can set `p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\My Dir";` attribute, so relative paths get calculated relative to the working dir.